# if i add single reducer in redux store it works fine but when i add second reducer or wrap that single reducer in brackets in my store it shows error

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

{i am working on a MERN stack project. In my frontend i am using redux for state management. but i am facing while fetching products from backend if i add single reducer in redux store to fetch All Products it works fine but when i add second reducer to get Product details or wrap that single reducer in brackets in my store it shows error and fetch all products also gives
{products: Array(0), loading: false, error: ''}

**error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: products.map is not a function
    at ProductList (ProductList.jsx:31:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

here is my code

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { productSlice, productDetailSlice } from "./Slice/ProductSlice.js";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
products:productSlice.reducer,
productDetails:productDetailSlice.reducer
},
});

export default store;
```

**ProductSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/getProducts",
  async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("/product/");
    return res.data;
  }
);

export const getProductDetails = createAsyncThunk(
  "productDetail/getProductDetails",
  async (id) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/product/${id}`);
    return res.data;
  }
);

export const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: {
    products: [],
    loading: false,
    error: "",
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getProducts.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getProducts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.products = action.payload.products;
    },
    [getProducts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
export const productDetailSlice = createSlice({
  name: "productDetail",
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    productDetail: [],
    error: null,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getProductDetails.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getProductDetails.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.productDetail = action.payload.product;
    },
    [getProductDetails.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

**ProductList.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Banner from "../../Components/Banner/Banner";
import Footer from "../../Components/Footer/Footer";
import Heading from "../../Components/Heading/Heading";
import Navbar from "../../Components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Product from "../../Components/Product/Product";
import "./productlist.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getProducts } from "../../Redux/Slice/ProductSlice.js";
import Loader from "../../Components/Loader/Loader";

const ProductList = () => {
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  console.log(products);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProducts());
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Banner />
      <Navbar />
      {products.loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="filters"></div>
          <div className="products">
            <div className="list">
              {products.map((product) => (
                <Product
                  key={product._id}
                  name={product.name}
                  price={product.price}
                  seller={product.seller}
                  images={product.images}
                  id={product._id}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductList;


export default ProductList
```

**ProductDetails**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails } from "../../Redux/Slice/ProductSlice.js";

const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
  const product = useSelector((state) => state.product);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
  }, []);

  let price = 279.95;
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;

export default ProductDetails
```

Comment: Please also share the code that you tried that gives an error, and the exact error message word for word.

Comment: `import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { productSlice, productDetailSlice } from "./Slice/ProductSlice.js";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {products:productSlice.reducer},
});

export default store;`

Answer (score 1):

By changing from

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: productSlice.reducer,
});
```

to

```js
const store = configureStore({
   reducer: {
     products: productSlice.reducer
   },
})
```

you change the shape of your state.

What was `state.loading` before is now `state.products.loading` - and what was `state.products` before is now `state.products.products`.

You will have to change your selectors accordingly.